# Finding out list of parcels or feature are adjacent or overlap each other in FME

Tags: fme-form, fme-transformer, fme-flow

Actual Problem :

Let's consider small letter is building outline and capital letter is parcel. a is belong to A,B,C now I have to check if A,B,C are adjacent or not. This result I am getting in list format after SpatialRelator. Output 1 is I tried to collectively find out each parcel what is adjacent parcels.

[image]
[image]
By comparing same parcel shape file using SpatialRelator and performing test as Touches trying to find list of parcel are adjacent to it. I am getting right output also.

Input 1 : List of parcel are adjacent to parcel.

[image]

[image]

Output from above :

Secondly I am get parcel and building outline relationship in list format. In that list one or multiple parcels will be there under `_relationship` attribute. I would like to if there is more than one parcel relationship are those parcel is adjacent or overlapping each other. From above input1 I have to check whether those parcel are adjacent or not. I tried `CommonSegmentFinder` but it not working as expected.

Is there any better way to solve this ?

Considering if input will more than parcel or feature list which need to check whether adjacent or not.

Comment: Can I check the scenario? Let's say polygon A returns B and C in the results list. Do you want to know if B and C are touching? Or do you want to know if A is overlapping B or touching B? And whether A is overlapping C or touching C?

Comment: Updated description with actual problem. I have different logic if a is belong parcel is adjacent and different logic for if a is belong parcels is no adjacent ( overlapping or partial overlapping each other or full overlapping each other.)